# How to change function component code to class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a functional component  but I need in class component. So I tried to change this but had some error but I can't find what I'm missing.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import DateTimeRangePicker from '@wojtekmaj/react-datetimerange-picker';

function App() {
  const [value, onChange] = useState([new Date(), new Date()]);

  return (
    <div>
      <DateTimeRangePicker
        onChange={onChange}
        value={value}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
export default App
```

I tried this but it's not working:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import DateTimeRangePicker from '@wojtekmaj/react-datetimerange-picker';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super()
    this.state = {
      value:new Date()
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <DateTimeRangePicker
          onChange={() => this.setState({value:new Date()})}
          value={this.state.value}
        />    
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Why does the function version have *two* dates in the state where the class version only has *one*? Assuming the first one is correct (looks like it is from https://www.npmjs.com/package/@wojtekmaj/react-datetimerange-picker) your state in the second case should be an array of two dates too.

Comment: Ciao @jonrsharpe, I thought the same until I saw the npm page https://www.npmjs.com/package/@wojtekmaj/react-datetimerange-picker. But why???

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito it's a datetime _range_ picker, so presumably `[start, end]`.

Comment: there is an example with class https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-datetimerange-picker/blob/master/sample/Sample.jsx

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks  I didn't think of that , my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in [npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@wojtekmaj/react-datetimerange-picker), `onChange` function returns a value. So you could change class component like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import DateTimeRangePicker from '@wojtekmaj/react-datetimerange-picker';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      value:[new Date(), new Date()],
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <DateTimeRangePicker
          onChange={(value) => this.setState({value:value})}
          value={this.state.value}
        />    
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually The value is an array  , But I used single value that's why it didn't worked

Comment: @arunlazer so should be something like `alue:[new Date(), new Date()],` correct?